# Out of memory en react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

tengo un proyecto en react native con expo y esta sobre typescript, actualmente mi proyecto esta en [**Development builds**](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/introduction/) porque uso modulos nativos y solo se ejecutan en este aspecto, estuve probando la app y arreglando errores (nada gravez) pero estoy teniendo de la nada el problema de OUT OF MEMORY (estoy probando en Android la app), este problema me lo salta desde java, pondre el error:

```
ERROR  Your app just crashed. See the error below.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8208 byte allocation with 565368 free bytes and 552KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.
 okio.Segment.<init>(Segment.kt:62)
 okio.SegmentPool.take(SegmentPool.kt:87)
 okio.Buffer.writableSegment$okio(Buffer.kt:1805)
 okio.Buffer.write(Buffer.kt:1624)
 okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.kt:183)
 okhttp3.RequestBody$Companion$toRequestBody$2.writeTo(RequestBody.kt:152)
 com.facebook.react.modules.network.ProgressRequestBody.writeTo(ProgressRequestBody.java:52)
 com.facebook.flipper.plugins.network.FlipperOkhttpInterceptor.cloneBodyAndInvalidateRequest(FlipperOkhttpInterceptor.java:119)
 com.facebook.flipper.plugins.network.FlipperOkhttpInterceptor.intercept(FlipperOkhttpInterceptor.java:91)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpNetworkInterceptor.intercept(ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpInterceptors.kt:22)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpAppInterceptor.intercept(ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpInterceptors.kt:53)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpAppInterceptor.intercept(ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpInterceptors.kt:53)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

la app se crashea de la nada, he estado leyendo sobre este error y esta muy relacionado con manejo de estados y eventos que no se limpian lo cual ocasiona fugaz de memoria y hace que pase esto, en los estados estoy usando **[Zustand](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/getting-started/introduction)** para manejarlos globales y en cuanto a eventos no tengo alguno que necesite limpiar, alguna recomendación de que hacer? o solución? herramientas para debuguear eso?

Estoy limpiando lo de los estados y ver si es por eso, otra cosa que sospecho es que talvez podría estar relacionado con la re-renderizacion de algunas cosas, he visto otros posts donde ajustan la memoria en el archivo app.json para incrementarla pero no optare por ese camino ya que no es recomendable aumentarla y forzar eso, mas bien ocupo alguna recomendación o forma de saber exactamente que esta pasando ya que el código realmente funciona bien.